# Azure Resources Health Monitoring

Tags: azure, health-monitoring, azure-monitoring

What's the best way to add health monitoring to all of my Azure resources in bulk with email notifications.

I can almost see all the information I'm looking for here:
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Insights/AzureDiagnosticsBladeWithParameter/defaultFilter.....

But I don't see a way of creating an email subscription to tell me any time a warning or error message occurs for any of the resources in my subscription. Can this be set up using PowerShell?

It would also be nice to add health check monitoring to all Cloud Services so that if any of the defined Endpoints no long respond to requests, the Cloud Service is marked unhealthy and sends an email notification.

Is there any way to set up this kind of management in PowerShell? It's easy in AWS...

Comment: The link you provide links to your own portal. We can't login to your portal. Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: It's just the link to the Service Health blade in the Azure Portal (new one not classic)

Comment: If you don't mind 3rd party commercial services, look into CloudMonix @ http://cloudmonix.com - it supports monitoring vast majority of Azure resources, sets everything up in a few minutes, and supports Cloud Services in addition to all sorts of other endpoints

Answer (score 0):

For the ping test scenario, consider using webtests provided by Application Insights. Refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability)

For general resource health scenario, there is the new Azure Resource Health service but it doesn't support general alerting today. More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/resource-health/resource-health-overview)